# What is the OpenCV equivalent of this image-sampling code in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, opencv

I'm trying to perform downsampling so I can create a gaussian pyramid in opencv. Right now I'm trying to translate this MATLAB code, and I'm not sure if my approach is right.

```
R = R(1:2:r, 1:2:c, :);
```

So this code only retrieves the odd-numbered pixels of an image. I read the documents of opencv and thought that the resize() method would be the one I'm looking for. 
https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize

```
Imgproc.resize(src,dest,new Size(), 0.5,0.5, INTER_NEAREST);
```

But I'm not sure if this code will retreat only the odd numbered pixels though... Do they show the exact same behavior?

Comment: Why not just write a simple unit test and try it?

Comment: @Dan Masek I'm running it on Android Studio and debugging in that IDE is a real burden : (

Comment: I'd just use Python, [like this](https://pastebin.com/cTDRhqBK) -- no hassle involved :) | If you do end up using resize for such downsampling, I'd suggest to wrap it in an appropriately named function and explain what's going on.